# iOS: When does iPhone switch from wifi to mobile network?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking

I am developing an iOS App which main function is to communicate with devices in a local wifi network. Which means a wifi connection is required but internet connection is not.

Additionally the app tries to fetch some data (like current software version, info about critical update etc.) from the internet when the app starts.

Now i have a test scenario. A wifi network without connection to the internet. iPhone is logged in to this wifi. When the app starts the behaviour is unpredictable.

Sometimes the data fetching from the internet fails due to the fact that the wifi has no internet connection. But in 20-30% data fetching from the internet works fine. In this case you can see that the wifi symbol disappears and the LTE symbol appears for two or three seconds and than the wifi symbol appears again.

Obviously sometimes my iPhone switches from wifi to mobile network to fetch some data and than back to wifi and sometimes not. Is it possible to control this behaviour?

Here is my code for fetching the data from internet:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl.com/data.xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&error];
if(dictionary){
    currentOne = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"versions"] valueForKey:@"myapp"] valueForKey:@"current"];
    nextOne = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"versions"] valueForKey:@"myapp"] valueForKey:@"next"];

    if(currentOne && nextOne){
        //Check app versions
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"--------------------------------------");
    NSLog(@"Versions dict empty - no internet connection");
    NSLog(@"--------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: Use reachability to determine if you are connected to Wifi.  If you are, set the request to not use cellular data.  I haven't tried this.  No idea if it will help.  No idea whether the behavior of other apps will still cause problems, even if, by some miracle, this works.

Comment: @Farley: Did figure out the condition for network switching?

Comment: @Raj_168: I did not. No idea how to control this behaviour.